# Choosing react component's type at runtime in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a react app in which I'd like to choose the type of component at runtime. I'm using ES6 and JSX.

Here's my code:

```
import Canvas from '../components/Canvas'
import CanvasTextbox from '../components/CanvasTextbox';


....

export default class CenterPane extends React.Component {

...

render() {
        const canvasKids = [];

        //for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        //   canvasKids.push(<CanvasTextbox key={i} id={'CanvasTextbox1'} />);
        //};

         for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
             let kid = this.state.kids[i];
             let CanvasComp = kid.type; // evaluates to 'CanvasTextbox '
             canvasKids.push(<CanvasComp key={i} id={kid.id} />);
             console.log(canvasKids)
         };



        return (
            <div>
                Canvas:
                <Canvas
                    name="myCanvas"
                    addChild={this.onAddChild.bind(this)}
                >

                    {canvasKids}


                </Canvas>
           </div>

        );
    }

}
```

When I refer to the component by name, (as in the commented `for` loop), it works. However, if I try to use the name from a variable, it doesn't.

I tried assigning the name to a capitalized variable, as guided in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime), but still nothing.

My canvas component indeed has the child, but it's not a react component, as seen in this react devtools screengrab:

[image]:

The component is not rendered on the canvas at all.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you use as JSX "tag" has to resolve to a **function** (lowercase names representing HTML tags are the exception). If `kid.type` resolves to a string, then it doesn't work.

You'd have to build a `name => component` map first:

```
const components = {
  CanvasTextbox,
};

// ...

let CanvasComp = components[kid.type];
```

Comment: You, sir, are a lifesaver. Works like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a general expression as the React element type. If you do want to use a general expression to indicate the type of the element, just assign it to a capitalized variable first. This often comes up when you want to render a different component based on a prop:

```
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  // Wrong! JSX type can't be an expression.
  return <components[props.storyType] story={props.story} />;
}
```

To fix this, we will assign the type to a capitalized variable first:

```
import React from 'react';
import { PhotoStory, VideoStory } from './stories';

const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  // Correct! JSX type can be a capitalized variable.
  const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
  return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

Please refer the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) for more details.