# Converting meta data into React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Say I have a list of components in my `src/components` folder in an ES6/React application. In a parent component I have a JSON object like:

```
{
  "name": "mycomponent",
  "props": {
     "label": "hello"
     "message": "world"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to import the component called `mycomponent` simply based on the string representation? And then utilize that component also based on the string?

Comment: If you create a `name => component` lookup map, yes. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40417644/218196

Comment: There's another example of such a lookup map in the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime).